# login into Jira using Integrated Windows Authentication or NTLM

Tags: c#, java, authentication, jira, single-sign-on

We are evaluating Jira and would like to login into it using Integrated Windows Authentication or NTLM (i.e. automatic logon without providing username and password, by using the domain user).

We have Jira 4.1.2 installed on a Tomcat 6.0.29, with Tomcat fronted by IIS 7.

When a user accesses the application, he first goes thorough IIS. Credentials are transmitted at this point and IIS forwards to Tomcat which greets us with the Jira login page. Jira users are setup the same as those from the domain, so the user must retype the user name and password for his domain. This is annoying.

Further more, not all users have passwords as some of them login using security cards + PIN, so there is no password for them to insert.

What we want is that, based on the credentials of the user, to automatically login into the Jira application, and not be greeted by the Login page.

From what we've studied, this seems to revolve arount combining Jira with Crowd, which we don't want to install just for this purpose alone.

Also found something related to writing a [custom authenticator](http://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-seraph/latest/sso.html) but not really sure what to make of it. Performing different developments (dot.NET and/or Java) won't be a problem if it isn't very hacky or some huge workaround.

So, is there a way to login into Jira using Integrated Windows Authentication / NTLM?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in our experience we had to use Crowd, we couldn't find an easy way around it.  You could try using an LDAP based approach (if your AD supports LDAP calls and if you have a simple structure etc), but it sounds like your setup is more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Jira 4 does not yet support NTLM authentication: http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?threadID=43247

Jira 4 + LDAP + Active Directory works, but does not give you SSO.

Answer (score -1):

The following add-on provides Integrated Windows Authentication (Kerberos) for any web app using Atlassian Crowd as its user management system, including Jira, Confluence, Stash and Bamboo: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.cleito.iwaac

Comment: Answers referring to 3rd party plugins are generally frowned upon by the SO community.